# For which value of parameter $k$ is the following system consistent?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

For the following system to be consistent,
$$\begin{cases}−7x − 5 y  + 4 z  &=& −4\\  −33x − 19 y  + k z  &=& −7 \\ \ \ 6x + 2 y  − 9 z  &=& −2 \end{cases}$$
we must have,
k
≠ ?

Comment: We must have a non-zero triple scalar product.

Comment: @Andrew Chin: non zero [triple product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product) without adjective "scalar". It would be simpler for the asker to give the condition $k$ must be such that "the principal determinant of the system is non-zero".

Answer (score 0):

The rank of the augmented matrix is 3.Solve det(coefficient matrix)=0 for $k$. For that value of $k$ the rank of the coefficient matrix is less than 3.The system is consistent iff k is not equal to that particular value you just found.